# Selecting correct settings for the order of Minkowski distance

Tags: python, text-mining, distance, scipy

I am looking to compute the distance between vectors of word frequencies (and I am new to this). I am trying out the Minkowski distance as implemented in Scipy.
The documentation asks me to specify a "p", defined as:

```
p : int ; The order of the norm of the difference ||u−v||p||u−v||p.
```

where u and v are my input vectors.
From the Wikipedia page I gather that p must not be below 0, setting it to 1 gives Manhattan distance, to 2 is Euclidean.
But I am still wondering about

- what an appropriate setting for p is and what it depends on;
- and more generally, what "the order of the norm of the difference" above means and what this p actually does?

Edit:
I have read up on this further, and this refers to the mathematical norm. According to [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4216305&tag=1),

> The Minkowski norms form a family of norms parametrized by their exponent *p*
> [...]
>
> When *p* = 2, the Minkowski norm corresponds to the euclidean one [...]
>
> For *p* = 1, it [...] induces the Manhattan [...]
>
> The limit for *p* [...] is the “max-norm,” which induces the Chebychev metric.

Several papers such as [Aggarwal et al](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44503-X_27) now suggest that fractional norms (i.e. < 1) work better for high dimensional data. They define this as > 20 variables. Euclidean distances, for instance, tend to "concentrate" in those datasets and do a bad job of establishing the distance between data points.

Comment: Welcome to our site! I've tried to edit the question to make its statistical focus a bit clearer (and removed some of the niceties at the end - we tend to have a "to the point" style here, although the lack of "thanks" etc can feel impolite at first!). Although the question has been phrased in terms of selecting settings for a Scipy function, the core idea here is about the order $p$ of the Minkowski distance and is definitely on-topic here.

Comment: Additionally, is it possible to use fractions for p?